# Get the first N elements of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: if you ever need to find a function to do something with an array go here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php and look through the functions.

Comment: rather than coming over to SO !?

Answer (score 457, accepted):

Use **array_slice()**

This is an example from the [PHP manual: array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 3);   // returns "a", "b", and "c"
```

**There is only a small issue**

If the array indices are meaningful to you, remember that `array_slice` will reset and reorder the **numeric** array indices. You need the `preserve_keys` flag set to `true`to avoid this. (4th parameter, available since 5.0.2).

Example:

```
$output = array_slice($input, 2, 3, true);
```

Output:

```
array([3]=>'c', [4]=>'d', [5]=>'e');
```

Answer (score 35):

You can use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) as:

```
$sliced_array = array_slice($array,0,$N);
```

Answer (score 12):

In the current order? I'd say [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php). Since it's a built in function it will be faster than looping through the array while keeping track of an incrementing index until N.

Answer (score 8):

[array_slice()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_slice.asp) is best thing to try, following are the examples:

```
<?php
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$output = array_slice($input, 2);      // returns "c", "d", and "e"
$output = array_slice($input, -2, 1);  // returns "d"
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 3);   // returns "a", "b", and "c"

// note the differences in the array keys
print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1));
print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1, true));
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

if you want to get the first N elements **and also** remove it from the array, you can use `array_splice()` (note the 'p' in "splice"):

http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.array-splice.php

use it like so: `$array_without_n_elements = array_splice($old_array, 0, N)`

Comment: Using array_splice you don't need to make a new array, after array_spliced $old_array will became itself the "array without n elements". Use only array_splice if you don't need anymore the original array with all its elements. So it doesn't gets the elements as asked, it removes the last n elements from the orginal array.