# array operation - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
$region_array = array( 

                                1 => 'Region 01', 
                                2 => 'Region 02',
                                3 => 'Region 03'
        );
```

What I'm trying is

`array_slice($region_array, $index);` & `array_splice($region_array, $index);` both does not give me required output.

Required output is

1. if the pass 2 as the index only 1st two element should be left. if I pass 3 1st three element should be left. How can I do it?
2. Then whatever the output array is I want to add 0 => 'Select Region' as the 1st option of the output array. I tried `array_push`. It adds the element to the end of the array. How can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php get the first N elements of an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720096/php-get-the-first-n-elements-of-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array_slice($region_array, 0, $index)
array_unshift($array, 'Select Region');
```

read the documentation for [array_slice](http://php.net/array_slice) and [array_unshift](http://php.net/array_unshift)

Comment: you don't need to use `array('0' => 'Select Region')`, in fact, I think that will push an array on to the front and make it two-dimensional.  just need `array_unshift($array, 'Select Region');`

Answer (score 4):

To answer point #2 first, use `array_unshift` -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

To point #1, use `array_slice($region_array, 0, $index);`

Answer (score 3):

```
`<?php 
    $region_array = array( 
        1 => 'Region 01', 
        2 => 'Region 02',
        3 => 'Region 03'
    );
    $array = array_slice($region_array, 0, 2);
    array_unshift($array, 'Select Region');
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);
 ?>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your array indices are greater than zero you can use this one-liner as well:

```
$result = array('Select region') + array_slice($region_array, 0, $index, true);
```

The `+` operator works on arrays and concatenates the second array (only the items whose key doesn't intersect with the first).