# How to get each error from error log file?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, error-handling, filesystems

I want to get each error in the log error file.

So if the file contains:

```
[08-Jul-2018 08:12:04 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method DateTime::fomat() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\theme\index.php on line 44

[08-Jul-2018 08:22:22 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database.table' doesn't exist' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\theme\index.php:37
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\news_theme\index.php(37): 
PDOStatement->execute()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template-loader.php(74): 
include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php(19): 
require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php(17): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#4 {main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\theme\index.php on line 37
```

These are two errors, But one of them is very long and takes more than one line.

I want to get each error of them in a variable.

I tried:

```
$contents  = file(get_template_directory().'/errors.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach ($contents as $key => $content) {
    echo $key . $content . '<br>';
}
```

But that gets each line, So the second one would be stored on several variables and I want to get each error in a variable.

Is that possible?

Comment: Try [`preg_split('~^\s+(?=\[\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4} \d+(?::\d{2}){2} \w{3}])~m', $contents)`](https://regex101.com/r/p9jSdT/2), see the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/VwEkXC).

Comment: `Warning: preg_split() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`, $contents is an array with the lines of text

Comment: I changed it to `$contents = file_get_contents();` then `$contents = preg_split();`, But it returns an array with one value which is the whole text

Comment: Well, probably I misplaced `^`, try [`'~\s+(?=^\[\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4} \d+(?::\d{2}){2} \w{3}])~m'`](https://regex101.com/r/p9jSdT/4). You may still read a file line by line, check if a line `preg_match('~^\[\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4} \d+(?::\d{2}){2} \w{3}]~', $line)` and add the lines to a temp var before you find another line matching that pattern or end of string is found.

Comment: I tried the `preg_split('/\s+(?=^\[\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4} \d+(?::\d{2}){2} \w{3}])/m', $contents);`, And it worked, What exactly will it match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file in as a *single string* with `file_get_contents`, and then use

```
$splits = preg_split('/\s+(?=^\[\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4} \d+(?::\d{2}){2} \w{3}])/m', $contents);
```

The pattern matches

- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces followed with...
- `(?=^\[\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4} \d+(?::\d{2}){2} \w{3}])` - a positive lookahead that, immediately to the right of the current location, requires:

  - `^` - start of a line (due to `m` modifier)
  - `\[` - a `[` char
  - `\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4}` - 2 digits, `-`, 3 word chars, `-`, 4 digits
  - - a space
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?::\d{2}){2}` - 2 occurrences of `:` and 2 digits (same as `:\d{2}:\d{2}`)
  - - a space
  - `\w{3}` - 3 word chars (letters, digits or `_`)
  - `]`  - a `]` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p9jSdT/4).

Comment: So it matches the `[08-Jul-2018 08:12:04 UTC]` and `[08-Jul-2018 08:22:22 UTC]`, or other parts ?

Comment: @Dan Almost, it matches 1+ whitespaces that are followed with values like `[08-Jul-2018 08:12:04 UTC]` *only* at the start of lines. Since the datetime pattern is inside a lookahead, they are not consumed and thus are kept in the output.

Comment: That's great as it doesn't match specific words or characters

Comment: @Dan Correct, though you can always make it more specific if you want to make it "safer". E.g. [`\s+(?=^\[\d{2}-(?:Jan|Feb|Ma[ry]|Apr|Ju[nl]|Aug|Sept?|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{4} \d+(?::\d{2}){2} [A-Z]{3}])`](https://regex101.com/r/p9jSdT/5).

Comment: Could I specify a limit?, For example to get the latest 10 errors, The latest lines are the newest

Comment: @Dan It is not possible, get them all and then use [`array_slice`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720096/get-the-first-n-elements-of-an-array).

Answer (score 0):

Your code just prints **every** input line one by one, along with its number.

To divide the input into chunks, concerning each error, you can take
the following approach:

- Read the **whole file** into a variable.
- Perform e.g. `preg_match_all` on it.

The regex to use shoud match:

- `^\[[^\]]+\]` - the initial part - date / time between brackets, from
  the start of line (due to `m` option).
- `[^\n]+` - A sequence of chars other than `\n` - the rest of this line.

And now the rest - optional non-capturing group - `(?:...)?`, containing:

- `\nStack trace:` - the starting part of the "longer" message, againg
  from the start of line.
- `.+` - the "middle part" - actual content of the stack trace.
  Due to `s` option it matches also `\n` chars, ending these "middle" lines.
- `\nthrown` - the last line to match - *thrown* from the start of line.
- `.+?$` - any number of any chars, up to the end of this (last) line.

To match multiple lines and start / end of each line,
use `m` and `s` regex options.

Below you have an example program, matching a constant text, instead of
the input file:

```
<?php
$text = <<<'EOD'
[08-Jul-2018 08:12:04 UTC] PHP Fatal error: on line 44
[08-Jul-2018 08:22:22 UTC] PHP Fatal error: in ...:37
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\news_theme\index.php(37): 
PDOStatement->execute()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template-loader.php(74): 
include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
thrown in ... on line 37
[08-Jul-2018 08:12:45 UTC] PHP Fatal error: on line 155
EOD;

$pattern = '/^\[[^\]]+\]\D+\d+\n(?:Stack trace:.+\nthrown.+?$)?/ms';
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches))
    print_r($matches[0]);
?>
```

It prints just 3 matches, as needed.

### Edit

If you have also other cases of errors, try another regex:

```
^\[[^\]]+\][^\n]+(?:\n[^\[\n][^\n]+)*
```

this time, only with `m` option. It matches:

- `^\[[^\]]+\][^\n]+` - The "starting" line - `[...]...`.
- `(?:\n[^\[\n][^\n]+)*` - Any number (including 0) of non-empty following
  lines, not starting from `[`.

For a working example concerning this last regex, see
https://regex101.com/r/0IUkc0/1

Comment: Thanks, But the file will contain various errors, Not just those two, What 3 matches? There are just 2 errors.

Comment: I tested my code using *http://rextester.com/l/php_online_compiler* and it runs without any error. If your log file contains other errors, maybe you should expand my regex (the non-capturing group), to match also other alternatives. Maybe it should be any line not starting with `[`.

Comment: Three matches are for the example source string in my code. Of course, your sample contains only 2 errors.

Comment: Each error, notice or warning will has a datetime next to it like `[08-Jul-2018 08:12:04 UTC]`, Maybe that could be used as a separator, What do you think ?

Comment: I assumed that each "finding" should start with `[...]` (date / time) from the start of line and then any number of "following", non-empty lines, starting from other char (not `[`). Do you want to match **only errors**, skipping messages of other classes?

Comment: I want to get anything inserted there, So no specifications like specific word, I think the time/date separator would be good

Comment: I tried `$contents = preg_split('/^\[[^\]]+\][^\n]+(?:\n[^\[\n][^\n]+)*/', $contents);`, It returned two indexes the first is empty and the second one contains the second error

Comment: You didn't use *m* option. I think, this is the cause. Note my remark after "Edit": ... with *m* option.

Comment: If you have a problem with regex, a good testing tool is *regex101.com*