# Sizeof() limit in php

Tags: php

There are 50 `<span class='numer'></span>` in example.com

With this code, I get 50 `<span class='numer'></span>` but I want to just get first 10 `<span class='numer'></span>` in example.com . How can I do it?

```
 function srch($bas, $son, $article)
    {
      @preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($bas, '/') .
      '(.*?)'. preg_quote($son, '/').'/i', $article, $m);
      return @$m[1];
    }

$link = "http://example.com/";
$inside = file_get_contents($link);
$sp = srch("<span class='numer'>","</span>",$inside);
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($sp);$i++)
echo "$sp[$i]";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the first N elements of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720096/get-the-first-n-elements-of-an-array)

Comment: `$i<10` probably?

Comment: Probably have to do `$i<min(10,sizeof($sp))`

Comment: I try, it does not work