# Limit the Json response results to top 5 in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, laravel

I have a search bar where upon searching i get all the related products, i want to display just top 5 of them

```
 public function getProducts()
{
    if (request()->ajax()) {
        $search_term = request()->input('term', '');
        $location_id = 1;
        $check_qty = request()->input('check_qty', false);
        $price_group_id = request()->input('price_group', null);
        $business_id = request()->session()->get('user.business_id');
        $not_for_selling = request()->get('not_for_selling', null);
        $price_group_id = request()->input('price_group', '');
        $product_types = request()->get('product_types', []);

        $search_fields = request()->get('search_fields', ['name', 'sku']);
        if (in_array('sku', $search_fields)) {
            $search_fields[] = 'sub_sku';
        }

        $result = $this->productUtil->filterProduct($business_id, $search_term, $location_id, $not_for_selling, $price_group_id, $product_types, $search_fields, $check_qty);

        return json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the first N elements of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720096/get-the-first-n-elements-of-an-array)

Comment: I would advise you to use Laravel collections instead of simple arrays and return Json responses the Laravel way instead of json_encode. that would make limiting the result a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `->limit(5)->get()` to get only 5 product from query

Use `orderBy('column_name', 'desc' or 'asc')` for sorting the results of the query

You can use laravel standard **response json** to send back response instead of wrapping inside **json_encode**

> `return response()->json($result)`

Comment: return response()->json($result)->limit(5)->get();

Comment: how to call bro

Comment: can you show the code of `$this->productUtil->filterProduct`

Comment: `$result = $this->productUtil->filterProduct($business_id, $sku, null, false, null, [], ['sub_sku'], false, 'exact')->first();

            if (!empty($result)) {
                return ['variation_id' => $result->variation_id,
                        'qty' => $qty,
                        'success' => true
                    ];
            } else {
                $error_msg = trans("lang_v1.sku_not_match", ['sku' => $sku]);
            }
        }`

Comment: `$this->productUtil->filterProduct($business_id, $sku, null, false, null, [], ['sub_sku'], false, 'exact')->first(); ` This is not a query brother.

Add `->limit(5)` before `->get()` function in your Eloquent query